# How to delete google cloud storage images using wildcards or pattern matching

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have used the cloud storage for storing the website images.
I have to delete the images through PHP. I have implemented the solution to delete a single object but how can I implement a solution with regular expression matching the pattern so that I can delete the images in a bunch by matching the wildcards or pattern.

For example:
I have the image name as "0066-1343-YBLK_IMG-1740_16x24_110.jpg"
I have to match the image names with any number instead 1740 after IMG- in above name.
So that we can delete only these images which are matching with the pattern.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to first list the objects using the API:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-php

and then match the object names against your pattern and delete those.  AFAIK, there is no API to directly delete objects that match a pattern.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. implemented the solution with the same way that is first listed the images and then matched using PHP and deleted one by one.